# raml syntax - nested API resources name - usage of curly braces

Tags: api, yaml, api-design, raml

A standard raml example:

```
#%RAML 0.8

title: World Music API
baseUri: http://example.api.com/{version}
version: v1
/songs:
  get:
  post:
  /{songId}:
    get:
    delete:
```

Resources are:

```
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/{songId}
```

So, if I want to add more APIs to this document, I can do this:

```
http://example.api.com/{version}/books
```

My question is that if the following is legal?

```
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/upload
```

If yes, how does raml differentiate the following APIs? (e.g. a songId that is "upload")

```
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/upload
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/{songId}
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/upload/{songId}
```

If not, then as long as the curly braces {} shows up in any level, no more resources can be defined for that level? then how should I define an upload API in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think RAML has provision against ambiguous resource URIs. But the tooling you use to implement your API may not be able to distinguish between them.

IMO the real limitation is the user experience you want to provide the consumers of your API.

In your case, one could image POSTing a new song details here:

```
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs
```

then POSTing its bytes data there:

```
http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/{songId}/data
```

There's no path ambiguity with this approach.

Comment: could you elaborate more about "RAML doesn't has provision against ambiguous resource URIs."?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant that the RAML spec doesn't prevent defining resources that have ambiguous matching. The only limitation I've found is related to avoiding slashes in path parameter values: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#template-uris-and-uri-parameters , which is kind of obvious.

Comment: I see. so is it my implementation that decides if `http://example.api.com/{version}/songs/upload` is for upload function or it's about a song whose id == "upload"?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.